# Genie.jl app stops running after I start it with up() function and close Julia

Tags: julia, genie.jl

I would like to deploy Genie.jl app. So, I start it using `up()` function with user specified hostname and port and also async=true. Later I closed Julia expecting the app to work but it doesn't.

May I know what should I be doing?

Thank you

Comment: What do you mean by " I closed Julia expecting the app to work" ?

Comment: I mean, I ran up() function opened the webpage URL it worked and then closed Julia I did not run down() function. And then I opened the same URL it did not work. I want genie.jl app to work in the background even when I close Julia.

Answer (score 0):

xgdgsc's skepticism is right.

When you close Julia, there is nothing running your code anymore, so your web app shuts down. You need to look into hosting services if you don't want to host it yourself/ leave your computer running Julia 24/7.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I found is to use `tmux`.

Run Genie.jl app in tmux and detach tmux session and it runs in the background.